# A Puzzle for Rio

Tags: crossword-clues, wordplay

The following list contains 30 clues describing 30 unique English words or well-known names, all of which have one thing in common.

The objective of the puzzle is to find the words associated with the clues.

Simple enough, but to change things up a bit I've divided the clues into three groups: **A**, **B**, and **C**. Puzzlers are requested to only post the complete solution to **one** group (the choice is up to you), and to only post **one** solution per user. This way, users needn't solve all thirty clues, and at least three users will share in the spoils of solving the puzzle.

The "correct answer" check will go to the first correct solution posted (for any group).

This format is somewhat experimental, hence any feedback is welcome [on this meta thread](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/are-the-following-mass-producible-puzzles-acceptable-on-puzzling-se-and-is-it-a). :)

---

**Group A**

1. every investor has one
2. a roaring good sign
3. Mr. Limbaugh's medium
4. Waitaminit! Isn't he that actor...?
5. Where art thou?
6. dress like a Tahitian
7. An apartment, a workplace, a place of creation. All of the above.
8. one difficult, confused situation
9. because mono is old hat
10. nothing but rainforest

**Group B**

11. let those notes fly hot and fast
12. Ballet, opera anyone? I am your host.
13. Where else would we put the barbeque and the deck chairs?
14. a bounder, but at least a seductive one
15. bought it at a novelty store
16. with some milk for dipping
17. a feast for the ears
18. full of bull
19. a fraction of an answer
20. the corporate head (abbr.)

**Group C**

21. Are you vaccinated?
22. a group of three
23. OK, picture the following...
24. I can't believe it's not butter!
25. now available in streaming and -on-demand flavours
26. a nosey little fellow
27. vivacity, not the cheese
28. that's some slow music
29. it's a word from the heart
30. what a nut

Comment: In fact this question consists of three independent puzzles, so this should be three separate questions.

Comment: @Victor: I'd appreciate it if you could contribute your viewpoint to the meta thread I've linked above. Currently there is no site policy on multi-answer questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group C

> 21. polio
>
> 22. trio
>
> 23. scenario
>
> 24. oleo
>
> 25. video
>
> 26. pinocchio
>
> 27. brio
>
> 28. adagio
>
> 29. cardio
>
> 30. pistachio

Answer (score 2):

11.let those notes fly hot and fast

> Capriccio

12.Ballet, opera anyone? I am your host.

> Maestro?

13.Where else would we put the barbeque and the deck chairs?

> Patio

14.a bounder, but at least a seductive one

> Lothario

15.bought it at a novelty store

> Curio

16.with some milk for dipping

> Oreo

17.a feast for the ears

> Audio

18.full of bull

> Rodeo

19.a fraction of an answer

20.the corporate head (abbr.)

> CEO

The empty space is there because

> I'm still missing a last "e-o's"

Answer (score 1):

**Group A**

every investor has one

> portfolio

a roaring good sign

> Leo

Mr. Limbaugh's medium

> Radio

Waitaminit! Isn't he that actor...?

> DeCaprio

Where art thou?

> ..Romeo?

dress like a Tahitian

> Kahikio

An apartment, a workplace, a place of creation. All of the above.

> studio

one difficult, confused situation

> imbroglio

because mono is old hat

> stereo

nothing but rainforest

> Borneo

Comment: 3, 6, 9, 10 are all correct. You've _almost_ got the right theme for the others, but not quite. (For 7, you have the right theme, but the word is incorrect. Think "pertaining to sound" more generally.)

Comment: After reviewing the previous answers... I think I get it. You're right, I'm close, but I'm a _little_ off.

Comment: Changing my answer to group A.